# Problema al recibir Json Array en put

Tags: sql-server, nodejs

Hola muy buenas tardes he realizado una api rest en node JS y al recibir Array Json, para poder actualizar datos en una base de datos SQL-Server, la api me recibe un objeto indefinido y no realiza ninguna función.

Aqui les muestro el método actualizar de mi api .

```
router.route('/').put(function(req,res){

var array= req.body;

 console.log(array.body);

  for(let i in array){

   console.log("entramos al for");

    conn.connect().then(function(){

     var transaction = new sql.Transaction(conn);

      transaction.begin().then(function(){

       var request = new sql.Request(transaction);

       request.input("id",sql.Int, array[i].id);

        request.input("fecha_programacion",sql.Date,
           array[i].fecha_programacion);

  request.execute("actualizar_act_programadas").then(function(){

    transaction.commit().then(function(recordset){
        conn.close();

      }).catch(function(err){
        conn.close();
        res.status(400).send("nos caimos en el commit");
      });
    }).catch(function(err){
      conn.close();
      res.status(400).send("nos caimos en la ejecucion del procedimiento");
     });

  }).catch(function(err){
    conn.close();
    res.status(400).send("se nos callo en traslation begin");
  });
}).catch(function(err){
  conn.close();
  res.status(400).send("Se nos callo la conexion");
});
   }

    res.status(200).send("ok");
  });
```

al recibir un Array Json el sistema recibe un indefinido, y envía una estado 200

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cómo estas enviando el array desde el front?

Comment: const array = [{
                                         id: 15,
                                        fecha_programacion: '2954-10-21'
                                         },
                                        { 
                                           id: 3,
                                           fecha_programacion: '2500-03-22'
                                          } ];
fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/programadas/', {
method: 'POST',
body: JSON.stringify(array)
              })
.then((response) => console.log(response.status))

Comment: pero al momento de enviarlo lo reprocesas con un **stringify**, por ahi debe estar el problema; trata cambiando esta linea `var array= JSON.parse(req.body);`

Comment: hola buenas tarde realizando lo que haz sugerido y haciendo un console.log(array) sigue siendo indefinido y no realiza ninguna función, agradezco la ayuda igualmente

Comment: Fijate que estas enviando la info a un método post y la API que estas utilizando es la put..

Comment: Gracias por la apreciación y dedicación @PauloUrbanoRivera como usted dijo lo he cambiado en el fetch, por put  y sigue con el mismo   error SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Que estas utilizando para enviar datos a tu API? Angular? AngularJS? Ajax?

Comment: la api esta construida en Node JS y esta recibiendo datos de un formulario php normal, para actualizar datos de  una base de datos sql-server